# Proof of Dilworth's theorem using PHP

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

I'm trying to prove "Dilworth's theorem" using Pigeonhole principle.

#### Definitions

Let $ (X,\le)$ be a **partially ordered set**, it means:

1. $\forall x \in X: x\le x$
2. $\forall x ,y\in X: x\le y,y\le x\implies x=y$
3. $\forall x ,y,z\in X: x\le y,y\le z\implies x\le z$

A **chain** is a $A\subseteq X$ s.t  $\forall a\ne b \in A: a\le b \ \vee \ b \le a$.

An **anti-chain** is a $B \subseteq X$ s.t $\forall a\ne b \in A: (a,b) \notin \le $ (every two different elements are not comparable)

#### The theorem

Let's say $ (X,\le)$ is a  **partially ordered set** of size $n^2+1$. Prove there is a chain or an anti-chain of size $n+1$.

#### My attempt

We need to use the PHP.A naive way is to set - pigeons $:=$ chains of size $i$ (subsets of $X$ which are chains). I'm not sure how to continue.

Can you help me to continue/finish the proof, please? (if you do, I'd like to know also the explanation "behind" figuring it out)

Comment: If those are your pigeons, then what are your holes? How many pigeons and holes do you have?

Comment: I thought Dilworth's theorem was "In a poset, the minimum chain partition is the same size as the largest antichain." You can prove your "$n^2+1$" theorem using the theorem in this comment as a stepping stone, but I do not think you can prove your "$n^2+1$" theorem using PHP alone.

Comment: @MikeEarnest That's how they called this theorem in University (don't ask me why :D). Eventually I proved the theorem mentioned here by PHP (I will explain if you want to) .

Comment: @Lior I am curious to see your proof. If you post it as an answer, and it is correct, I'll upvote it.